# how do I host flask or Django website using a json file on another server's directory... other server is discord bot

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, api, python-multithreading

I have a discord bot that outputs a json file. Now I need to use this json file in another project where I make a website to display statistics.

I can either use Flask or Django but I am not sure if I can host both projects in an instance of Heroku or AWS's ssh directory...

I made a flask api that reads the json file and displays the json per url but it will not run at the same time as the bot on one script... Running both files does work concurrently so maybe I can host the api on the same instance as the bot and then request to such urls. Not sure at all how I would even load this onto the cloud though...

Comment: Can you please share where does the discord bot puts the json file?
In normal cases, you need a background process that will periodically pull the json file.

Comment: So it saves locally in the same directory of the discord bot python file. 
I set up an AWS instance but need to - get both files on there - set up a domain - run the discord bot server and the api at the same time - make a whole new app that uses requests to grab from the api urls